# Is it possible to sort a dictionary in Julia?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, data-structures, julia

I have created a dictionary out of two arrays using `zip()` like

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,19]
dictionary1 = Dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

Now i want to sort this dictionary by `key(list1)` or by `list2`. Can somebody show me a way or function, how to realize it?

Comment: The Dict in base is unsorted, but you can use SortedDict from the DataStructures.jl package: https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sort also takes a `by` keyword, which means you can do:

```
julia> sort(collect(dictionary1), by=x->x[2])
5-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1,6)
 (2,7)
 (3,8)
 (4,9)
 (5,19)
```

Also note that there is a `SortedDict` in DataStructures.jl, which maintains sort order, and there's an `OrderedDict` which maintains *insertion* order.  Finally, there's a pull request which would allow direct sorting of `OrderedDicts` (but I need to finish it up and commit it).

Comment: A more concise and better answer than mine when sorting by values.

Comment: :thumbs_up: for the distinction between `SortedDict` and `OrderedDict`—not to be confused!

Answer (score 7):

While `SortedDict` may be useful if it is necessary to keep the dictionary sorted, it is often only necessary to sort the dictionary for output, in which case, the following may be what is required:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,19]
dictionary1 = Dict(zip(list1,list2))
sort(collect(dictionary1))
```

... which produces:

```
5-element Array{(Int64,Int64),1}:
 (1,6) 
 (2,7) 
 (3,8) 
 (4,9) 
 (5,19)
```

We can sort by values with:

```
sort(collect(zip(values(dictionary1),keys(dictionary1))))
```

... which gives:

```
5-element Array{(Int64,Int64),1}:
 (6,1) 
 (7,2) 
 (8,3) 
 (9,4) 
 (19,5)
```

Comment: @Simon, by any chance do you know how to fix an error that arises because the zip automatically made the keys into 'SubString' ? `ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Array{SubString{String},1} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.`

Answer (score 2):

The `byvalue` keyword for the `sort` function (or `sort!` for mutating/in place sorting) is useful for sorting dictionaries in order of their values (as opposed to their keys). The result will be of type OrderedDict from [OrderedCollections.jl](https://juliacollections.github.io/OrderedCollections.jl/stable/) (it's also re-exported by [DataStructures.jl](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/stable/)).

```
list1 = [2,1,3,4,5]
list2 = [9,10,8,7,6]
dictionary1 = Dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

Sort by value (i.e. by list2):

```
sort(dictionary1; byvalue=true)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict{Int64, Int64} with 5 entries:
  5 => 6
  4 => 7
  3 => 8
  2 => 9
  1 => 10
```

Sort by key (i.e. by list1):

```
sort(dictionary1)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict{Int64, Int64} with 5 entries:
  1 => 10
  2 => 9
  3 => 8
  4 => 7
  5 => 6
```