# How do I sort a dictionary by value in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have two arrays:

```
a = [11,22,33,44,55]
b = [66,77,88,99,100]
```

which I used to create a dictionary by doing:

```
combined_dict = Dict(zip(a, b))
```

How can I sort the Dictionary **by value**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin dictionary type (`Dict`) is unordered so it is not clear what you are asking for -- it can't be sorted. If you want an ordered dictionary you can use an `OrderedDict` from the [`OrderedCollections`](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/OrderedCollections.jl) package:

```
julia> a = [11,22,33,44,55];

julia> b = [100,99,88,77,66];

julia> combined_dict = OrderedDict(zip(a, b))
OrderedDict{Int64,Int64} with 5 entries:
  11 => 100
  22 => 99
  33 => 88
  44 => 77
  55 => 66
```

In order to sort by value you can use the `byvalue=true` as a keyword argument to sort (`byvalue=false` is the default, i.e. sort by keys):

```
julia> sort(combined_dict; byvalue=true)
OrderedDict{Int64,Int64} with 5 entries:
  55 => 66
  44 => 77
  33 => 88
  22 => 99
  11 => 100
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort the tuples **by lexicographic order**, you can simply do:

```
julia> sort(collect(zip(values(combined_dict), keys(combined_dict))))
5-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (66, 11) 
 (77, 22) 
 (88, 33) 
 (99, 44) 
 (100, 55)
```

See this post for reference: [Is it possible to sort a dictionary in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848734/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-dictionary-in-julia)

[Learn more about the `sort` function here.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/#Base.sort)

[Learn more about the `collect` function here.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.collect-Tuple%7BType,Any%7D)

[Learn more about the `zip` function here.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.zip)

Comment: This doesn't actually sort by values, it sorts the tuples in lexicographic order. Try to e.g. reverse `b`, i.e. `b = [100,99,88,77,66]`.
If you want an array with the pairs from the dictionary you can simply `collect` the dictionary, and pass `by = x -> x.second` to sort by the values: `sort!(collect(combined_dict); by = x -> x.second)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort the dictionary value it is not needed to use the `OrderedDict`.
Using the `sort` function would suffice for your use case.

```
julia> a = [11,22,33,44,55];

julia> b = [100,99,88,77,66];

julia> combined_dict = Dict{Int, Int}(zip(a, b))
Dict{Int64, Int64} with 5 entries:
  22 => 99
  55 => 66
  33 => 88
  11 => 100
  44 => 77

julia> sort(combined_dict, byvalue=true)
OrderedDict{Int64, Int64} with 5 entries:
  55 => 66
  44 => 77
  33 => 88
  22 => 99
  11 => 100
```

Tested on `Julia 1.6`